# Go: Global variables

Tags: go

I can easily make an object global by defining it outside of any function, but this does not work for certain structs that must be created.

What I'm trying to do is a much more complicated version of this:

```
package main
import "regexp"

func doSomething(test []byte) []byte {
   test = reg.ReplaceAll(test,nil)
   return test
}

reg, _ := regexp.Compile(`[^a-z\s]`) // this is the issue

func main() {
   thing := doSomething("somebytes")
}
```

Obviously the above is not allowed, but that's what I'd like to do.

There does not appear to be any way to make that `reg` object accessible from within the `doSomething` function without passing it, which I want to avoid because I'm going to be doing this several billion times.

If I put it in `main()` then it's no longer global. I've even tried this:

```
var reg regexp.Regexp
func main() {
   reg, _ = regexp.Compile(`[^a-z\s]`)
   thing := doSomething("somebytes")
}
```

...but that doesn't work either, it gives me an error.

Any ideas?

Update: My issue is not actually with regexp. That was an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's allowed just fine, you can use:

```
var reg = regexp.MustCompile(`[^a-z\s]`) //or even
var reg, _ = regexp.Compile(`[^a-z\s]`) // MustCompile is the better choice though.
```

Also keep in mind that `regexp.Compile` / `regexp.MustCompile` returns a pointer, and that's why your 2nd attempt didn't work, you were assigning `*regexp.Regexp` to `regexp.Regexp`.

Full [example](http://play.golang.org/p/Z6__Ajj8Mx):

```
func doSomething(test []byte) []byte {
    test = reg.ReplaceAll(test, nil)
    return test
}

var (
    reg, _ = regexp.Compile(`[^a-z\s]`)
    reg2   *regexp.Regexp
)

func init() { //different way of initializing global valuables
    reg2 = regexp.MustCompile(`[^a-z\s]`)
}

func main() {
    thing := doSomething([]byte("somebytes"))
    fmt.Println(thing)
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I obviously stick haven't got the knack of this. It was the one thing I didn't think of trying. I'll accept your answer when it lets me. Thanks!

Comment: I added a full example and explained why your 2nd attempt didn't work.

Comment: Using global variables might be seen as less favorable (i.e. "namespace pollution"). If your problem is about always passing a copy when passing the var between the different functions, using a pointer within the function calls would prevent this copying.

Comment: Not in Go, unless he capitalize the name, it's a private variable for that specific package.

Comment: @ABri you cant seriously suggest all regular expressions should be initialised in main() and then passed through all the functions to get down to where they are needed. :o

Comment: @OneOfOne package in question is main

Comment: @Jacob : Where did i suggest such?

Answer (score 2):

The short declaration syntax

```
reg, _ := regexp.Compile(`[^a-z\s]`)
```

is not allowed for global scope. Use `var` explicitly instead.

```
var reg, _ = regex.Compile(`[^a-z\s]`)
```